# PayPal Sandbox checkout 'continue button' - Unable to locate element: - C# WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, paypal, ui-automation

I've taken a good look around, however haven't been able to find the specific answer i'm after; hoping someone is able to point me in the right direction.

I'm automating a PayPal checkout process with WebDriver 2.53 in Visual Studio 2015 using C# against the Firefox driver. My flow into PayPal is fine, being able to login through the sandbox environment. However when I get to the confirmation screen following the initial login, I appear to be unable to select the continue button.

[image]

My code is:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.TagName("iframe")));
var emailAddressLogin = driver.FindElement(By.Id("email"));
emailAddressLogin.SendKeys("EMailAddress");
var password = driver.FindElement(By.Id("password"));
password.SendKeys("Password");
var login = driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnLogin"));
login.Click();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
var ContinueButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"confirmButtonTop\"]"));
ContinueButton.Click();
```

Once it gets to the `confirmButtonTop` selection, I'm always returning:

> An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"confirmButtonTop"}

I have tried to locate the button via XPath, ID etc but nothing seems to allow the selection and always returned with "Unable to locate element".

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fevZ1.png)

Has anyone had issues with the 'continue' button within the PayPal sandbox environment, or advise what i'm missing? I have tried to switch focus but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Could it be that you have another iframe or you are not in the same iframe but in the main window?

Comment: I did think that and added 'driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.TagName("iframe")));' before trying to locate and select the continue option; however to no avail.

I will add the full HTML of the section i'm looking at to the main description

Comment: Add the html with the section for this if possible.  I have a test for paypal and I don't have any iframe in my case, but after login i make sure that i am logged in waiting for css selector "#contactInfo .confidential" and in my case for continue i click using css selector "#step #continue"

Comment: Should be added and linked (HTML) within the main description.I'm sure it does seem to be some form of switch focus/iframe type thing, but seem to be struggling to work out what i need to switch to.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so having done a little more searching I have found that by adding the following to my code before the button selection to work:

driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());

So the end code looked like:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.TagName("iframe")));
var emailAddressLogin = driver.FindElement(By.Id("email"));
emailAddressLogin.SendKeys("EMailAddress");
var password = driver.FindElement(By.Id("password"));
password.SendKeys("Password");
var login = driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnLogin"));
login.Click();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
var ContinueButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"confirmButtonTop\"]"));
ContinueButton.Click();
```

This was taken from [Selenium webdriver selecting new window c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028449/selenium-webdriver-selecting-new-window-c-sharp) and thanks to joinsaad