# Unable to switch to newly opened tab in chrome using selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, browser-automation

I opened a new tab from a link in current page. The tab opened but the focus is not shifted to that tab, nor am I able to switch tab using the following two methods I used. I'm using Chrome.

```
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN);
BaseClass.driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathOfLinkToPage2)).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);

 //method one 
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(BaseClass.driver.getWindowHandles());
BaseClass.driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
//method two
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab2 = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.TAB);
BaseClass.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab2);
```

Comment: Why making your steps complicated by using `ArrayList<String> tabs`? Can you consider traversing through WindowHandles? Thanks

Comment: could you show me an example. I am a new to this

Comment: Can you consider showing a bit of your work please along with your actual manual steps? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
// open Site 1
String site_1_Window= driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println(site_1_Window);
// open Site 2
Set site_Windows= driver.getWindowHandles();
System.out.println(site_Windows);
for (String site_2_Window: driver.getWindowHandles())
{
  System.out.println(site_2_Window);
    driver.switchTo().window(site_2_Window);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

also see this: http://www.binaryclips.com/2016/03/selenium-webdriver-in-c-switch-to-new.html and this [Selenium webdriver selecting new window c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028449/selenium-webdriver-selecting-new-window-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

//count and enter your tab index beside get

```
ArrayList<String> newTab = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(newTab.get(2));
```