# Getting error when switching window in IE11 on windows10

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, windows-10

I am running selenium script in IE11 on windows 10 an getting below whenever i try to switch to a new window:

1. Error retrieving current window
2. Unable to get browser

However the same code is running fine in IE11 on windows 7. I have tried changing regedit for IE tried setting capabilities. Still facing the issue. Can anyone kindly suggest a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Which version of IE11 are running on both hosts? Which Selenium version are you using? Show us how you setup the iedriver.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to post a sample code when you post any question may help community members to understand the issue and help to make a tests.

You said that you had modified some registry settings. I suggest you to reset those registries and reset IE browser again.

Try to use C# code example below may help to switch window.

```
//switch to new window.
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());

//if you want to switch back to your first window
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.First());
```

Below is an C# example for switch to new window by comparing the title of the window.

```
protected static Boolean SwitchWindow(string title)
            {
                var currentWindow = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
                var availableWindows = new List<string>(driver.WindowHandles);

                foreach (string w in availableWindows)
                {
                    if (w != currentWindow)
                    {
                        driver.SwitchTo().Window(w);
                        if (driver.Title == title)
                            return true;
                        else
                        {
                            driver.SwitchTo().Window(currentWindow);
                        }

                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
```

References:

(1) [Selenium WebDriver in C#: Switch To new window or tab](http://www.binaryclips.com/2016/03/selenium-webdriver-in-c-switch-to-new.html)

(2) [How can I switch to new window using webdriver?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/how-can-i-switch-to-new-window-using-webdriver)

(3) [Selenium webdriver selecting new window c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028449/selenium-webdriver-selecting-new-window-c-sharp)

If issue persists than try to provide detailed information about your issue. We will try to test the issue to find the cause for the issue.